# Constrain layout is not working on all android devices screen size

Tags: java, android, android-studio, layout, android-constraintlayout

I have the following layout, it works fine for big screens like note 9 Samsung, but it will not shrink to fit the screen size in small phones, please refer to the attached picture and codes.
I like to use the constraint layouts , I did choised all items to be in form of WRAPCONTENT or MATCHCONSTRAIN , but still have the start button jump out of screen in small phones .

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/scroll"
    tools:context=".teamselect">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/team1EdtTxt1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="148dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="148dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="49dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="49dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="اللاعب 1"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/team1EdtTxt2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/team1EdtTxt2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="148dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="148dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="49dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="49dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="54dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:editable="false"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="اللاعب 2"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/team1EdtTxt1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/team2EdtTxt1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="148dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="148dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="49dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="49dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="اللاعب 1"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/team2EdtTxt2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/team2EdtTxt2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="148dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="148dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="49dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="49dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="اللاعب 2"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/team2EdtTxt1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="209dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="209dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="129dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="41dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="41dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:text="الفريق الاول"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:fontFamily="@font/advent_pro_thin"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/team1EdtTxt1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="209dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="209dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="41dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="41dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:text="الفريق الثاني"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/team2EdtTxt1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/team1EdtTxt2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="110dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="110dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="110dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttondomeno"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/team2EdtTxt2" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: You can't add static margins if you want the design to be flexible, use dimens file for all various screen resolutions to get best result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to @Hamza Khan answer, try to avoid using any fixed sizes on your views, you can use this layout:

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/team1EdtTxt1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="اللاعب 1"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/team1EdtTxt2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/team1EdtTxt2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:clickable="false"
        android:editable="false"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="اللاعب 2"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/team1EdtTxt1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="الفريق الاول"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/team1EdtTxt1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="الفريق الثاني"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/team2EdtTxt1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/team2EdtTxt1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:clickable="false"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="اللاعب 1"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/team2EdtTxt2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/team2EdtTxt2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="اللاعب 2"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/startBtn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/team2EdtTxt1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="start"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.3" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.50" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.10" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**It will look like this:**

[image]

Notice that I have used 2 very useful attributes:

```
  app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"
  app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.3"
```

In addition, I have used [Guidelines](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html) so now if you want to change the look of your layout you can simply change this attrubute:

```
  app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.x"
```

Comment: thanks, that's the right answer that I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't fit because of fixed text sizes and margins in your views
You can try one of two things:
1) use ScrollView to make the layout scrollable
2) Remove hardcoded sizes and use different dimensions for different screen sizes

Comment: Add such answers in comments.

Comment: Thanks for replay, I didn't use any hardcoded, it is only the guidelines, I used wrap content and match constraint in all items.

Comment: You used  android:layout_marginBottom="22dp", use it from dimens file for various screen resolutions.

Comment: @Karan not enough reputation

Comment: @amer Alot of margins are hard coded in your edittext views

Comment: I never worked on a Dimensions file before, and Constrain layout never failed me before, can you try to post an example?

Comment: I reduced the top margin to 10 from 128, now it does fit the small screens and big ones, margins are not a hardcoded, that is a normal distance to a constraint layout, this is the way I use in many apps that I created.

Comment: after practicing, I got the best way to make screen fits all the screen sizes, use constrain layout + guidelines is the best solution. notice that you need to NOT make the guideline with margin, it MUST be a percentage.